# unknown folder delete within a directory using .BAT files

Tags: batch-file

I have a folder "FolderA" which contains three sub-folders: foldera1 foldera2 and foldera3

I need to write a batch file which resides inside "FolderA". It should delete all the folders under "FolderA" as a cleanup activity. I don't know the folder names. `rmdir` does not support wild cards.

Could someone provide a solution for this small problem?

Comment: Just added the double quotes, to be able to delete directories with spaces in their name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

something like :

```
for /f %%a in ('dir /ad /b') do (rmdir /S /Q "%%a")
for /d %%a in (*) do (rmdir /S /Q "%%a")
```

should do the trick. The second form allow some wildcard selection for directories.

To test it outside a script, in a plain DOS session:

```
for /f %a in ('dir /ad /b') do (rmdir /S /Q "%a")
for /d %a in (*) do (rmdir /S /Q "%a")
```

Note the **double quotes**, in order to be able to delete directories with spaces in them.

Answer (score 3):

From command line:

```
for /D %a in (*) do rd /S /Q %a
```

In batch/cmd file:

```
for /D %%a in (*) do rd /S /Q %%a
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are inside FolderA, run "rmdir /s /q ."

This shows an error on command line of "file in use..."
Yet, it deletes the directory inside it.